# Изменить формат вывода даты

Tags: javascript, java, gson

Есть объект на java, в котором есть поле типа java.util.Date. Этот объект потом сериализуется в формат json с помощью гугловской библиотеки Gson. Затем он десериализуется в javascript'е с помощью стандартного JSON.parse(). На выходе это поле типа Date имеет формат "авг 15, 2017". 
Как изменить этот формат вывода на такой - "08/15"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о формате даты в json'e, то просто добавьте соответствующий TypeAdapter:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, (JsonSerializer<Date>) (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(src)))
            .create();
```

Если без лямбды, то так:

```
.registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonSerializer<Date>() {
                @Override
                public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                    return new JsonPrimitive(dateFormat.format(src));
                }
            })
```

Comment: С json ещё только начал разбираться. Если собирать через билдер, то нужно все поля необходимого класса туда передать, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Нет, в данном случае достаточно ограничиться переопределением сериализатора для элементов класса Date, со всеми остальными полями Gson продолжить работать по дефолтным правилам.

Comment: То есть, после этого, просто сделать String strGson = toJson(объект моего класса)?

Comment: Либо я дурак, либо лыжи не едут. Пробовал так как написали Вы, но чет не получилось. Но Вы подсказали куда копать. Написал свой небольшой сериализатор своего объекта(который пересылал) и все получилось